# KeyListener doesn't work in Java

Tags: java

I don't know why KeyListener doesn't work.
The program should close if the user press "Shift".

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();

        //make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        guiFrame.setTitle("");
        guiFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        guiFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        guiFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        guiFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);


        JLabel jb1 = new JLabel("WER DAS LIEST IST BLÖD",JLabel.CENTER);
        jb1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 140));
        jb1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        jb1.setLocation((guiFrame.getWidth()-jb1.getWidth())/2,50);


        guiFrame.add(jb1);
        //This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry not shift, *space

Comment: There is an edit button near the bottom of your post. Utilize that for correcting mistakes in your post and adding any pertinent additional information. Do you get any errors? If you add debugging do you see your key released event called? What is the value of e.getKeyCode()?

Comment: If you want the app to exit when the user presses SHIFT, why are you testing for VK_SPACE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implementing the `KeyListener` interface is not enough - you need to add it to some component (in your case the `JFrame`).

Try something like

```
guiFrame.addKeyListener(this);
```

See here for the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener-java.awt.event.KeyListener-

And here for a the official tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html